# How to name parameter form for SysOperation batch job task in d365?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations, sysoperationframework

I have created a batch job using the SysOperation framework, I want to set title of the form which shows the parameters of the job. How can I do that?

The title is already shown is the name of the service class and the entry point method.
This is the dialog
[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://www.prashanthnagaraju.com/2016/05/sysoperation-framework-adding-caption.html

Comment: yes, it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add this method :

```
protected ClassDescription defaultCaption()
{
    ClassDescription ret = 'your caption';
    return ret; 
}
```